# c++ read char from file, convert to long long int

Tags: c++, file, atoi, unsigned-long-long-int

This is my function at the moment

```
long long int File::Getline3(int user1, long long int user3)
{
std::string filename = std::to_string(user1);

std::ifstream fin(filename + ".txt");
fin.getline (line1, 5);
fin.getline (line2, 5);
fin.getline (line3, 20);
fin.close();

user3 = (atoi(line3));

return user3;
}
```

Seems to return a most of the numbers, but not all, and in a jumbled up format.

Not sure if my error lies in reading the line (getline) or converting it (atoi) or returning it.

(line1, line2 and line3 char declared in header file)

Line 3 is 16 digits long.

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you receiving?

Comment: expecting 1234567890123456, recieving 2147483647

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for `long long int` it should not be `atoi`, but `strtoll`:

```
long long int strtoll(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

supposingly `line3` is a string, you might use it as:

```
char* endptr = NULL;
user3 = strtoll(line3.c_str(), &endptr, 10);
```

and sice you marked it as `c++` you also can use: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoll/

**edit** after your comment: `strtoll` takes a `const char*` and converts its content into a `long long int`.  If  endptr is not `NULL`, `strtoll()` stores the address of the first invalid character in `*endptr`. You also can specify the `base` for the number.

You did `(atoi(line3));` but `atoi` also expects a `const char*` so I supposed that `line3` must be a `std::string` (due to the way you use it) that's why I gave a shot in the dark with the `c_str()` to get the actual data of the string, instead of the object itself..

Instead of `atoi` you can use of course `atoll` for long long stuff :)

Comment: awesome, worked a treat. However I don't like to just use stuff if I don't understand how it works, if it isn't too much trouble could you give a brief explanation of whats going on, or point me to a resource which could please?

Answer (score 0):

Read char by char from left end of the string as and compute and add to a cumulative as per place value.